# Roomle Model Falls Through Floor If Model Has Glass Like Material

Tags: roomle

A few of our furniture models have acrylic legs, which for some reason makes the model "fall" through the floor. If for example it's an acrylic bench with a fabric cushion on top, the model falls through 'till it reaches the bottom of the cushion.

Is this a bug in Roomle where when you apply a transparent material onto something it thinks it's actually not there? We've tried importing it with flipped planes underneath the legs to try and "trick" the configurator that there was some geo there without any transparency. But this did not work either.

If wanted, I can link to an example that we have. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Kind Regards,
Wade Morrison

Comment: Could you please provide a link to this configuration?

Comment: Yes of course! As soon as you move the camera you'll notice how it falls through the floor: https://www.roomle.com/t/cp/?configuratorId=scoutdesignstudio&id=scoutLabel:AllaneWaterfallBench&api=false

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your configuration is placed below the floor. The floor (where the shadows are) is placed exactly on coordinate 0.

Try moving your configuration up until you bottom of the product is on floor level.

You can find more information about scripting here: https://docs.roomle.com/scripting/resources/

Comment: Hey there! So we double checked everything, and the model's origin point is at coordinate 0 (world origin) already. But we went ahead and tried raising the whole model up (while keeping the origin at 0) and tried that, failed. And then we also tried programming it by MoveMatrixBy to each piece of the geo, and once we add that it shifts everything up as it's supposed to, but the floor is still attached to where it was on the bottom of the seat and the camera is then off focus as well.

Comment: The configuration you shared looks correct to me now. Shadows are on the bottom as expected?

Comment: Yeah we figured out a work around for now! We just duplicated the planes on the bottom of the chair, made them a separate mesh with a white floor material. So it looks invisible/part of the default scene, but really is just a trick to get it working right now. I am not sure if you'd like us to create another version with it falling through the floor so you can maybe figure out what's causing it? I assumed the renderer sees that there's alpha applied to the material so it makes it act like a "ghost" and lets it pass through the floor maybe?